# Select folder dialog for WPF, with path entry field

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

As is well-known, WPF still doesn't supply a folder selection dialog (unless WPF4 has one that I've missed).  In the meantime, I am using System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog.

Unfortunately, this dialog only has a folder tree, OK, Cancel, and an optional "Make New Folder" button.  The usability is poor.  Particularly, it is terrible when trying to select a network folder.  The only way to select the folder is to expand the "Network" base.. which on many corporate systems/networks, will begin a long delay and ultimately yield an unacceptably long list.

I would like a text entry field which would allow the user to start navigation at a particular location.. such as a particular computer/folder.. such as is possible in the file browse dialog.

Has anyone done such a thing?  Is this a way to extend the standard System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog, or will I have to create my own?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vista Bridge](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VistaBridge) provides managed wrappers for the new Vista dialogs with fallback support when running on older OS. These file dialogs are preferrable to either the stock WPF or WinForms ones.

The [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) provides managed wrappers for Windows 7 features.

Comment: This looks promising.  I downloaded the Windows API Code Pack and found that CommonOpenFileDialog has an IsFolderPicker Property.  If that's set, it should work as a folder picker.  I suspect that I would still have to have a fallback for backwards compatibility.. but, that's how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create your own, no default folder dialog implement something like this. If I'm not wrong, java too doesn't allow such possibility.

I normally create the "open folder dialog" button near a textbox where the path can be written manually (when the folder dialog button is closed with ok button simply fill that textbox), that's the easiest way.

Your type of dialog should be created, on the good side you can at least sell it because it looks nice and helpful. Or maybe you can find something similar on the web (previous payment by the way).

Another thing, all folders dialog are very slow, at least on windows XP, maybe is "impossible" to reduce those delays, you should do some searches to avoid this problem (multi-threaded dialog which gather information while giving possibility to start navigating through directory tree is the only thing i can think about).

Hope this will be helpful

**EDIT:**
Maybe this has some sort of utility,
http://www.ssware.com/fldrview.htm
it looks cool but doesn't have all features you want, I think it doesn't exist as you hope

Answer (score 0):

You wrap native code and use the SHBrowseForFolder function: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762115(v=vs.85).aspx

Or starting with Vista you could use create a COM object with the id "CLSID_FileOpenDialog" (native code, too):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776913(VS.85).aspx

Both of those provide a text input area where you can type in UNC paths.